# What is being passed while adding and listening stream and how is it being used?

Tags: dart, stream, flutter

I have been having hard time working with streams. I read many articles and finally wrote this code. I understand how streams work theoretically but the code isn't making much sense to me. It is working but I don't understand what exactly is happening.

This is how I defined my streamcontroller -

```
StreamController streamController = StreamController.broadcast();
```

This is what I added in initState() -

```
streamController.stream.listen((data) {
  //call my backend api
});
```

Based on some action, I am calling this -

```
streamController.add(someData);
```

I don't understand what is being passed while listening. I haven't defined `data` anywhere. I can't leave it null or empty. Where is it being used??

While adding also, what data am I passing?
If I need some data while calling my backend api. How do I pass it?
And do I always need to listen to my stream in `initState()` only? I am unable to add it anywhere else. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is the payload that is passed to you every time the stream emits an event.

```
(data) {
  //call my backend api
}
```

is a function that you pass to

```
streamController.stream.listen(...);
```

and this function is called every time the stream receives an event.

Just use

```
(data) {
  print('received data: $data);
}
```

and it should be clear.

Comment: While adding, why do I have to pass some data? Can I call multiple events that is can I pass multiple functions to streamcontroller.stream.listen()? And what if I need to pass some data in the function?

Comment: It would be easier if you had an example of a concrete problem. You can pass `null` if only the happening of the event is relevant but not the payload. "Can I call multiple events" not sure what that means. You don't call events. "I pass multiple functions". Single subscription streams (default) don't allow that, but you can call multiple functions from the function you pass to `listen`.

Comment: "if I need to pass some data in the function" also not sure what that means. The function (closure) has the context available where `listen(...)` is called and the function can access all variables, methods, ... available in this context.

Comment: Also use `forEach()` instead of `listen()` by default. `listen()` returns a `StreamSubscription` that allows to cancel the subscription before the stream closes. If you do not need that, prefer `forEach()`, it's a bit more efficient.

Comment: "You can pass null if only the happening of the event is relevant but not the payload" - What if the payload is relevant? How do I use the payload (that I am sending while adding) when I listen?

Comment: Thanks for telling me about `forEach()` - will try that. Also, `listen` and `forEach()` have to be in `initState()`? Can I listen to the stream anywhere else? And why is it so?

Comment: `initState` is only called once for a widget instance. If you call `listen()` or `forEach()` in `build()` (which is called frequently) you'll get an exception the 2nd time that the stream has already been listened to and if you broadcast stream (multi subscription), you'll add another event handler every time `build()` is called. So this has nothing to do with streams, only with Flutter widget lifecycle.

Comment: That makes sense. Could you please explain passing payload to the function I am calling in 'listen'?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with that or what is unclear. The value (payload) you pass to `.add()` is passed to every registered event handler `...listen((payload) { ... })`

Comment: This is what I did -  `streamController.add(``Hello There``);` and then while listening - `streamController.stream.listen((data) {
      print(data);
    });` . But I don't see any print. Is this wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce, this prints the data for me.

Comment: Oh damn. It worked. Thanks a lot for your time. Really helped a lot. :)

Comment: I am having similar troubles again, @Gunter. Please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55847858/how-to-detect-an-asynchronous-operation-is-over-in-streambuilder