# How to detect an asynchronous operation is over in streambuilder?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, flutter, stream

I am using `StreamBuilder` like this -

```
StreamController streamController = StreamController.broadcast();

StreamBuilder(
    stream: streamController.stream,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      return (snapshot.hasData == true)  //THIS CONDITION!!!
          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
          : myWidget();
)
```

I am adding to my stream like this -

```
onPressed: () {
     streamController.add(null);
 },
```

I am unable to understand the condition I should check to display the progress indicator or my widget. Since I am not passing any data, I can't use `hasData`. I tried passing dummy data but `hasData` never becomes false (even after the async function is over).
I tried using `connectionState` but that is always active. I have no idea why it is not changing to `waiting` state. It does when I use `FutureBuilder`. (I thought I could just check that if the state is `waiting`, show the progress indicator but that doesn't work. Why??)

Please help.

Comment: what do you want to achieve with your `streamController.add()` method? what should happen when `onPressed` is called?

Comment: I call an API and wait for it to finish.  Since it is little slow, I want to show progress indicator till it is done.

Comment: so you need a `FutureBuilder`, not `StreamBuilder`

Comment: This API is called when a button is pressed, so initially when the screen opens, I want `myWidget ` only to come. Don't we use `FutureBuilder` when we have to call an API on opening of a screen?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#4-fetch-and-display-the-data

Comment: I read that and what I understand is - future function is called at the opening of screen and indicator is shown till the function execution is done. My case on the other hand is - when I press a button, progress indicator should come and the earlier widget should come again after the function processing is done. Is that wrong?

Comment: if you want to rebuild your `Widget` you should call `setState` and initialize your API request there

Comment: I have to show an indicator while the process goes on.

Comment: yes, i know - use `FutureBuilder` for that

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Comment: i already gave you a sample code https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#4-fetch-and-display-the-data

Comment: ok then how do I call the future on press of a button? It is called usually in initState..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192412/discussion-between-keerti-purswani-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always when I have an async call that returns me Future data and also I need this response to update my UI layer using streams I think in BLoC pattern. Is needed a little bit more code but will simplify your problem and make your code more readable,  scaleable, and keep streams and async calls out from UI code as other things too.

In your case It's simple:

```
enum DownloadState { NO_DOWNLOAD,  DOWNLOADING, SUCCESS }
```

An enum to track what is the state of the `async` call a Network API call by example.

```
class Bloc {

  final ApiClass api = new ApiClass();   // simulating your downloader object
  final StreamController controller = StreamController<DownloadState>.broadcast(); 
  Stream get dataState => controller.stream; // exposing your stream output

 void _changeState( final DownloadState state ) => controller.sink.add( state );

  void downloadData(){
      _changeState( DowloadState.DOWNLOADING );     
      // assuming that this call returns a Future object.
      api.downloadData().then(  (yourNetworkData) {
         // handle your downloaded data 
        _changeState( DownloadState.SUCCESS );
       }  ).catchError( (apiError) =>  controller.sink.addError( apiError ); ); 
 }
}
```

A BLoC class that expose a stream and inside this class we create method that call a Network API by example and when the results is fetched we can hold the values, transform this values, send to UI using streams and other things. Here in `downloadData` after the Future object is completed we just put into stream a `DownloadState` value and this will force the widgets that are listening controller.stream be rebuilded in UI layer with `StreamBuilder` help. If we got some error from network call we put this in stream error output `controller.sink.addError` and in UI layer we'll able to check this with `snapshot.hasError` property.

In your UI layer...

```
Bloc bloc = Bloc(); // you can create a instance of BLoC in initState or in widget contructor...
StreamBuilder<DownloadState>(
    stream: bloc.dataState, // bloc get method that returns stream output.
    initialData: DownloadState.NO_DOWNLOAD. // this will be the inital value. It's optional
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData){
          switch(snapshot.data){
               case  DownloadState.NO_DOWNLOAD:
                  return NoDownloadWidget();
               case  DownloadState.DOWNLOADING:
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                case  DownloadState.SUCCESS:
                   return myWidget();
          }
      }
       return ErrorWidget( snapshot.error );
)
```

and in the onPress Event

```
onPressed: () => bloc.downloadData();
```

With this approach you remove of your UI layer stream objects and controllers, no setState calls is needed, you will have a specific file with your business logic and external api calls and this can make more easy this kind of job where we have Futures and Streams working together.

I Hope it helps.